# Export ubuntu CVS users

Tags: export, cvs, ubuntu-10.04

I have ubuntu server running and CVS is installed on it. I'll be managing CVS with the Webmin gui tool. I'm migrating the server to the new ubuntu edition. I could easily migrate the CVS repository to the new machine but how could I migrate/export CVS Users?. Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First migrate the users(Unix or ldap) or create the users with the same names providing password for each , then move the CVS repositories to the new machine.